# Mysqli: Looping queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, union

I need to perform 'n' unions using mysqli (where n changes based on user input). For instance:

```
select a from b where a=c[1]
UNION
select a from b where a=c[2]
...
UNION
select a from b where a=c[n]
```

Is there anyway to do this iteratively? Something like that:
for(i=1;i

Note: I can only run select queries on the database

Comment: Why not `select a from b where a IN (c[1], c[2], c[3], ... c[n])` and use PHP to generate `(c[1], c[2], c[3], ... c[n])`?

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal is there anyway to do this with 'LIKE'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for union

For numeric `a` it would be

```
$c = array(1,2,3);
$c = array_filter(array_map('intval',$c));
$in = implode(',',$c);
$sql = "select a from b where a IN ($in)";
```

for strings idea is pretty the same.

Comment: That seems to be enough for the problem at hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If always you need to `select a from b where a = dynamicvalue` you can save your  dynamicValue in a temp table or use a query like this:

> SELECT a FROM b WHERE a IN (SELECT c from x WHERE clause = anythings)